# Why we can move forward in case of backward slipping?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-kinematics

Suppose a wheel which is rolling with backward slipping.

My question is that, if every point which when touch the ground for a short period of time moves in backward direction with respect to ground,then why don't such a wheel always move backward?

Answer (score 1):

[image: Skidding wheel]

The diagram shows a wheel rotating backwards and therefore skidding along the ground as it moves forwards. Because the wheel is skidding there is a frictional force equal to the friction coefficient times the weight of the wheel:

$$ F = \mu mg $$

And this exerts a force $F$ on the wheel that produces a deceleration:

$$ a = - \mu g $$

So the equation for the velocity of the wheel is:

$$ \frac{dv}{dt} = -\mu g $$

giving:

$$ v(t) = -\mu g t + C $$

where $C$ is the constant of integration. And it's the constant of integration that eplains how the wheel can be moving forward even while it's skidding backwards. We get $C$ from the initial conditions so if at time zero the wheel is moving forwards we have $C \gt 0$. In this case the wheel will start out moving forwards, then it will slow to a halt, then start moving backwards.

Comment: In order to be moving forward,C should be greater than ugt, but how to prove it.

Comment: I would be very grateful if you can link any good material to understand these things like you. I have tried my textbook and also saw lectures on MIT OCW but couldn't got much understanding.Anyway, Thank you.